# How save textAreaInput() data in .bed format in shiny app?

Tags: r, shiny, textinput, shinyapps

I have a shiny like below, where I can add genomic coordinate and separate them by `Space`. I would like to know, how can I save data in a `.bed` format.

Code:

```
ui <- fluidPage(
textAreaInput("list", "Input List"),
actionButton("submit", "Submit",  style="color: white; background-color: gray; border-color: black"),
downloadButton("download", "Download results", style="color: white; background-color: gray; border-color: black"),
mainPanel(  textOutput("out") )
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  my_text <- reactive({
    data.matrix(input$list)
  }) %>% 
    shiny::bindCache(input$list
    ) %>% 
shiny::bindEvent(input$submit)
  output$out  <- renderText({
   my_text()
  })

## Download results
 shinyjs::disable("download")
observeEvent(my_text(), {
shinyjs::enable("download")
})

output$download <- downloadHandler(
 filename = ".csv",
 content = function(file) {
   write.csv(my_text(), file, row.names = FALSE,sep="\t")
  }
)
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

[image]

I would like to save them like below, each region in a given row and separated by `Tab`

```
chr1 10 20
chr2 20 30
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know anything about `bed` files or their specifications, and no information is in the question. However, if all you need to do is write tab-separated files that is a simple task. You can try using `write.table`, specifying `\t` (tab) as a separator. Here is a small example:

```r
write.table(x = df, sep = "\t", file = "file.bed)
```